# Flutter can be connected with an Elastic Search query?

Tags: firebase, sqlite, flutter, nosql, rasa

I try to develop a FLUTTER Mobile app with a RASA framework. I want to know, what type of database can be used? Firebase, Mysql, SQLite or NoSQL?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which database you are referring to, can you be more specific on that?  Are you using Rasa Open source or Rasa X?  The Rasa Open Source only really has a database for the tracker store if you decide to not use in memory so I'm not sure which database you are referring to.

https://rasa.com/docs/rasa/user-guide/running-rasa-with-docker/#adding-a-custom-tracker-store

Thanks

Comment: I used Rasa Open Source. as I want to use memory in out of the phone. can do it? As a database can use firebase?